# Static list property returning null

Tags: apex, failing-tests, null-pointer

I've built a property to setup test data within my test class, but my tests keep throwing 'Attempt to de-reference a null object' errors. I've been able to narrow it down to this property. I'm finding the data is initialized and inserted, but never returned:

```
    public static list<Account> companyAccounts {
      get 
      {
        if (companyAccounts == null) 
        {
            List<Account> companyAccounts = new List<Account>();
            Id rt = Util.getRecordTypeId('Account', 'ES_Client');
            for (Integer i = 0; i < 250; i++)
            {
                Account a = new Account(Name='MBOTest '+i, Phone='(124)456-7890', Industry='IT',
                                        RecordTypeId=rt, OwnerId=SFUsers[0].Id, Tier__c='5');
                companyAccounts.add(a);
            }
            insert companyAccounts;
            System.debug('companyAccounts insert complete: '+companyAccounts);
        }
        System.debug('beginning return: '+companyAccounts);
        return companyAccounts;
      }
    private set;
}
```

Here are the debug logs:

> 10:03:54:362 USER_DEBUG [328]|DEBUG|companyAccounts insert complete: (Account:{Name=MBOTest 0, Phone=(124)456-7890, RecordTypeId=012C0000000Q8EuIAK, OwnerId=005M00000060Th9IAE, Id=001M000000dmHnrIAE, Tier__c=5, Industry=IT}, ...)
>
> 10:03:54:362 USER_DEBUG [330]|DEBUG|beginning return: null

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: is it possible, that since you created companyAccounts inside the IF statement, you will not be able to return companyAccounts because it is outside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As jnoel100 points out in his comment, your local variable `companyAccounts` hides ([shadows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)) the `companyAccounts` property:

```
if (companyAccounts == null) {
    List<Account> companyAccounts = new List<Account>();
```

and its value is discarded when the block is exited. So instead you need to reference the same variable:

```
if (companyAccounts == null) {
    companyAccounts = new List<Account>();
```

This is such a common problem in many languages that tools such as the Eclipse Java editor warn you with a yellow squiggly underline when it occurs. AFAIK there is no such tooling for Apex at the moment.